# Same IIS local host labelled different name when loggin using differenit Alias

Tags: iis, server

When I logged in to the same IIS using different alias, the name on the local host is different.  I didn't change or do anything differently since the creation of this IIS. How it shows different names on different login account is unexplainable.

May I know if I make change on my end to match the one on the role account, it will not break things on this server. I checked with other admins, they see what the role account sees.  I am the only person that has name mismatched (it shows DEV instead of PROD).

[This is what I see when I log in as me under IIS connection DEVAPP01 (.../Luu). And this is what I see when I log in as a role account PRODAPP01 (..../roleAccountp1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFKcH.png)  So sorry the website doesn't allow me to post image yet.  I'm new to stackoverflow and hope I can get some advice here.

Changing the label is easy but I would like to make sure it doesn't break anything since this is PROD environment.  Thx

Regards,

Comment: Perfectly normal as this machine might have been renamed several times before you use it, and the caches left there are not removed. More details can be found in posts like https://forums.iis.net/t/1214977.aspx?Rename+IIS+8+Server+using+Script In most cases, that name is irrelevant to any web apps hosted, so people do not care much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out (with the help from our cloud team of course). I was told that at one point, the server was named DEVAPP01, later it was renamed to something else and I still connected to the wrong name on the same server.  To solve this problem, I:

1. In the IIS under connection, select Connect to Server and put in the right IIS name which is PRDAPP01, once I got in there, I saw two IIS 1) DEVAPP01 and 2) PRDAPP01
2. Select the wrong IIS name which was DEVAPP01 and right click and select Remove Connection (this option seated below Refresh)

Problem solved!!!

Thanks to my great cloud team from my company.